Does electric and magnetic field from electromagnetic radiation are 2D based?
I'm getting into physics, specially in electromagnetism.
When we're talking about electromagnetic radiation. Does it has a 2D shape when it's propagating through space?
Does Maxwell's equations explain this?
Thanks for reading

Maxwell explains classical radiation...but what do you mean by a 2D shape? Do you mean an expanding spherical front? Or the common beginner misunderstanding of waves in that they are drawn as 2D sine waves, i.e. a vector oscillating in a plane?

People often think and draw pictures in 2D. But the world is 3D. Here is are some fun videos from 3blue1brown that shows 3D images, among other things. Physics playlist. See the first couple on the Barber Pole effect.

Or perhaps you are thinking that in polarized light, the electric field vectors are all in the same plane, and the magnetic field vectors are all in another?

Please clarify what you mean by the "shape" of electromagnetic radiation. Classical electromagnetism is described by vector fields.
